# populate selected value with input box from dropdown list

Tags: dropdown, inputbox

I want to pupulate the selected value with input box from dropdownlist. I can show the dropdown list referring by the below site.
After the value selected, I want to reflect to the input box. Is is needed some change event?

I only changed button to input box.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <input onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"/>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Test1</a>
        <a href="#about">Test2</a>
        <a href="#contact">Test3</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `onclick` for each anchor to set the input box text from anchor `innerHTML`, check following solution

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <input id="txt" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" />
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home" onclick="document.getElementById('txt').value = this.innerHTML">Test1</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="document.getElementById('txt').value = this.innerHTML">Test2</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="document.getElementById('txt').value = this.innerHTML">Test3</a>
  </div>
```